# Laravel 5.0: session gets lost

Tags: session, laravel-5

On page redirect session gets lost and is not available in middleware.

What is the reason and how to rectify it? I am new to Laravel so don't have much information about this.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers but nothing could help and I found the answer that I am posting here.

Issue was that in the kernal.php I was declaring the middleware above

```
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
```

and when I placed my middleware below session as given below

```
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'App\Http\Middleware\mymiddleware',
```

things start working.

Now this seems obvious but as I am new to Laravel so couldn't track it earlier.

In any case thank you very much for all your responses.

Hope this may help others as well.

thx

Comment: That doesn't seem very obvious. ;p Facing a similar problem have been trying all the potential solution related to that bug. Still no luck. I am goint to try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify 'lifetime' variable in config/session.php file.

set this to 'lifetime' = 2400,

it will resolve your problem.

other wise use database cache in .env file

and create session tables in database.

the 2nd solution solved my problem.